# Debian - Network doesn't work on boot

Tags: debian, networking, virtualbox

I've setup my `/etc/network/interfaces`. But **I have to always restart my network**, not just start. `/etc/init.d/networking restart` on the system boot. Where is the problem? I want my network to **work automatically** on system boot up.

My /etc/network/interfaces config

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

**Same problem with DHCP.**

Maybe rc.local could work, but I don't think, it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Try to comment this source /etc/network/interfaces.d/* maybe there is a file overriding your configuration... Try this ls /etc/rc$(runlevel)/ | grep networking, if nothing appears you need to update-rc.d networking enable. Other thing i simply installed sysvinit sysvinit-core in all debian installations because services are not acting like you need in a unix system.

Comment: Didn't worked. Trying to find out, where could the problem be. Any ideas? also thanks for your answer @LucianoAndressMartini

Comment: Please post results for ls /etc/rc$(runlevel).d

Comment: Does removing the `allow-hotplug eth0` line help?